# Angular JS datepicker doesn't update model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to filter a table using a daterange, but can't get the model to update so it doesn't know what date I picked.

This is the HTML for the datepicker popup:

```
<label>From:</label> 
 <p class="input-group" style="width:200px">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup = "{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened"
                                           min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                                           ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
     <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
     </span>
 </p>
```

The JS code in my controller:

```
(function ()
{
'use strict';

angular.module('aml-tech-dashboard.successful-emails').controller('datepickerController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.dt = '';
    $scope.status = {
        opened: false
    };

    $scope.format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $scope.minDate = new Date();
    $scope.dateOptions = {
        //formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };

    $scope.open = function ($event) {
        $scope.status.opened = true;

    };

    });

})();
```

Table:

```
<tr ng-repeat = 'file in files | startFrom: dt'>
```

Comment: Hi Andreea. I notice that $scope.dt is not set to any value inside your $scope.$watch function

Comment: Hi, I removed that, It was something I used to just log it to my console and see if it detects changes when I select different dates. Assigning a value to $scope.dt didn't change anything though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tr` element is wrong. It should look like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in files | startFrom: dt"></tr>
```

You also have a mistake in the uib-datepicker-popup directive. It should look like this:

```
uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
```

This is assuming you have defined the `startFrom` filter elsewhere in your module, as it is not a built-in Angular filter.

Comment: Thanks, changed that, but it's still not updating the model. I think it's something wrong with my controller

Comment: Do you have a `startFrom` filter defined somewhere?

Comment: the uib-datepicker-popup directive thing was just me being bad at copy pasting, oops.

Comment: As I said, there is no built in startFrom filter in Angular, so that could be it

Comment: You're right, I changed that and it works now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$scope.dt = new Date();
```

and make sure that the controller is invoked when the view render.